# Aduino Due Can messages

Tags: programming, arduino-due

I am trying to read/send CanBus messages using a Arduino Due.

As of now I have used https://github.com/collin80/due_can library to setup my Can Bus interface.

I am using Vector Software CanAylzer to see what CAN message are being received.

This is where I have my issue.
Although the CanAylzer software is being able to detect Can Messages on the line it gives be a Bit error on bit position 119. All the fields of relevance for me ID,Data etc seem to be reported fine.

Here is a snapshot of the CanAylzer Error Frame. Below is my Arduino code . Any help would be awesome. 
[image]

Here is the ino code:

```
// Arduino Due - CAN Sample 1
// Brief CAN example for Arduino Due
// Test the transmission from CAN0 Mailbox 0 to CAN1 Mailbox 0


#include <Arduino.h>
#include "variant.h"
#include "due_can.h"

#define TEST1_CAN_TRANSFER_ID    0x18FF0017 //random 29 bits
#define TEST1_CAN0_TX_PRIO       1
#define CAN_MSG_DUMMY_DATA       0xABC

// CAN frame max data length
#define MAX_CAN_FRAME_DATA_LEN   8

// Message variable to be send
uint32_t CAN_MSG_1 = 0;

void setup()
{

   // start serial port at 115200 bps:

   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial.println("Program Started");

}

void loop(){

   CAN_FRAME frame1, frame2;
   // say what you got:
   Serial.print("Sent Value: ");
   Serial.println(CAN_MSG_1, DEC);

   // Initialize CAN0 and CAN1, baudrate is 250kb/s
   CAN.init(CAN_BPS_250K);
   CAN2.init(CAN_BPS_250K);

   //Initialize the definitions for the frames we'll be sending.
   //This can be done here because the frame never changes
   frame1.id = TEST1_CAN_TRANSFER_ID;
   frame1.length = MAX_CAN_FRAME_DATA_LEN;
   //Priority
   frame1.priority = 0;
   frame1.rtr = 1;
   //Below we set the 8 data bytes in 32 bit (4 byte) chunks
   //Bytes can be set individually with frame1.data.bytes[which] = something
   frame1.data.low = 0xAFAFAFAF;
   frame1.data.high = CAN_MSG_DUMMY_DATA;
   //We are using extended frames so mark that here. Otherwise it will just use
   //the first 11 bits of the ID set
   frame1.extended = 1;

   CAN.sendFrame(frame1);
   while (1) {
   }
}
```

#### Update

Ok so here are the printed(via serial port) values of various registers. I don't think it is a problem with the values in the registers. I have cross referenced these with the SAM3X/A (on the due) Micro-controller manual (chapter 41, pertaining to the CAN). The only one I am fishy about is the baudrate one.

```
Serial Port Initialized
******START OF LOOP ******
No of Sent frames: 1
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
CAN_SR:( Status Register)
Bits 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 7 | 6 | 5 | 4
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 11 | 10 | 9 | 8
      0 | 0  | 0 | 0

Bits 15 | 14 | 13 | 12
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 19 | 18 | 17 | 16
     0  | 1  | 1  | 0

Bits 23 | 22 | 21 | 20
     1  | 0  | 1  | 0

Bits 27 | 26 | 25 | 24
     0  | 1  | 0  | 0

Bits 31 | 30 | 29 | 28
     0  | 1  | 0  | 0

<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
#####END OF LOOP ######


Serial Port Initialized
******START OF LOOP ******
No of Sent frames: 1
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
CAN_MR: (Mode Register)
Bits 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
     0 | 0 | 0 | 1

Bits 7 | 6 | 5 | 4
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 26 | 25 | 24
     0  | 0  | 0
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
#####END OF LOOP ######

******START OF LOOP ******
No of Sent frames: 4
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
CAN_MID7: (Message ID Register Mailbox 7)
Bits 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
     0 | 1 | 1 | 1

Bits 7 | 6 | 5 | 4
     0 | 0 | 0 | 1

Bits 11 | 10 | 9 | 8
     0  | 0  | 0 | 0

Bits 15 | 14 | 13 | 12
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 19 | 18 | 17 | 16
     1  | 1  | 1  | 1

Bits 23 | 22 | 21 | 20
     1  | 1  | 1  | 1

Bits 27 | 26 | 25 | 24
     1  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 31 | 30 | 29 | 28
     0  | 0  | 1  | 1


Serial Port Initialized
******START OF LOOP ******
No of Sent frames: 1
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
CAN_ECR: (Error Count Register)
Bits 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 7 | 6 | 5 | 4
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 11 | 10 | 9 | 8
     0  | 0  | 0 | 0

Bits 15 | 14 | 13 | 12
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 19 | 18 | 17 | 16
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 23 | 22 | 21 | 20
     1  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 27 | 26 | 25 | 24
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 31 | 30 | 29 | 28
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
#####END OF LOOP ######
```

Lastly and most importantly in my opinion:

```
Serial Port Initialized
******START OF LOOP ******
No of Sent frames: 1
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
CAN_MSR7: (CAN Message Status Register Mailbox 7) 
Bits 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 7 | 6 | 5 | 4
     0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Bits 11 | 10 | 9 | 8
      0 | 0  | 0 | 0

Bits 15 | 14 | 13 | 12
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 19 | 18 | 17 | 16
     1  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 23 | 22 | 21 | 20
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 27 | 26 | 25 | 24
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 31 | 30 | 29 | 28
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
#####END OF LOOP ######
```

and the Baud rate register

```
******START OF LOOP ******
No of Sent frames: 1
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
CAN_BR: 
Bits 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
     0 | 0 | 0 | 1

Bits 7 | 6 | 5 | 4
     0 | 0 | 0 | 1

Bits 11 | 10 | 9 | 8
     0 |  0  | 1 |  0

Bits 15 | 14 | 13 | 12
     0  | 0  | 1  | 0

Bits 19 | 18 | 17 | 16
     1  | 0  | 0  | 1

Bits 23 | 22 | 21 | 20
     0  | 0  | 1  | 0

Bits 27 | 26 | 25 | 24
     0  | 0  | 0  | 0

Bits 28
     0
<><><><><><><><><>><><><><>
#####END OF LOOP ######
```

You can find what all the register bits details on Atmel's website or leave some way for me to email the documentation to you.

Any Help would be much appreciated!

### Update 2:

I have attached 2 different Oscilloscope readings and deconstructed the entire binary representation of the Can message manually. Furthermore I calculated the associated CRC's of the two different messages, and then compared them to the ones the hardware created and found them(hardware ones) to be incorrect. I have provided a link to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwRY4KO_k7sUdmN5RWJVZnFHSVE&usp=sharing) where the results from the Oscilloscope can be found.

PS: the messages I used had in one 7 A's(hex, i.e 28bits) for the ID and 16 A's for the Data field.
The second one had 7 C's for the Id and 16 C's for the Data field.

Both are 2.0B can extended frames.[image][image]

Comment: Looks like a CRC error. But the CRC calculation is done by hardware, so neither your fault nor the library's. Do you see a chance of monitoring the CAN line? If I'm not completely wrong, CRC for this frame should be 0x5F88

Comment: @mic the CANalyzer(pictured above) does that for me. I know its a problem with the CRC but why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Good question! :-) That Vector stuff is not perfect, but the tools (and especially the prices) are made for professional use. The only thing I can imagine at the moment is a slightly different baudrate and/or an improper tq setting in your CANalyzer. What happens if you play a little bit with the sampling point? And again: Do you have a chance to look directly at the CAN line (e.g. using a scope)? It would be interesting to know what the Arduino really transmits.

Comment: @mic how do I check the tq settings? I have checked all the registers on the hardware level as well they seem to have the correct information.

Comment: @mic also have you used vector software before?

Comment: I'm quite familiar with Vector. In Canalyzer, "Configuration" - "Hardware configuration", you will see your CAN channel, and in "Setup" you can adjust the sampling. Play a little bit with the settings and see what happens.

Comment: yeah *I did that but the issue was the prescalers dont match up for the baudrate. If I put a prescaler of 4 in my arduino side code it gives me a sync error if i try to put a higher scaler then there is no equivalent in CanAylzer

Comment: Of course the baudrates have to match EXACTLY. 250kb/s is a common baudrate for a mid speed CAN network. I'm pretty sure CANalyzer as well as the Arduino offers at least one parameter set for this baudrate. What is your master clock on Arduino?

Comment: its the SystemCoreClock defined in the system_sam3xa.h (due's MC) header

Comment: Sorry, but this discussion doesn't really show progress. Maybe it's a good idea to post all your Arduino register settings as well as your CANalyzer timing parameters.

Comment: @mic updated stuff

Comment: @mic you were initially right. I used an oscilloscope to track the signal and found out the CRC doesn't match up to what it should be. This I believe is throwing the bit error. Any advise on how to fix this ? All other fields are correct. Also the frequency and therefore the baudrate are correct. I calculated that from the scope measurements.

Comment: This is strange, as you have no influence on CRC calculation. But what I've noticed when analyzing your register settings: In CAN_SR, the "Warn" flag is set. This should not happen after only one transfer. Also the "AERR" is set. This may be ok, if CANalyzer has detected a bit error and thus doesn't send an acknowledge. Can you post the scope screenshot for the complete message?

Comment: @mic please See the Section Update 2.

Comment: @mic the WARN Flag is set correctly. Firstly because I am sending a message in a loop multiple time not only once. Secondly as per CAN protocol a failed transmission attempt will be followed by multiple re-transmission attempts up to 255 times. At which point the CAN Bus will be disabled. Reference pg 1219 SAM3X/A manual.